# Assigning values to lists within lists within lists within lists

Tags: c#

I have a hierarchy of lists within lists, and at the very bottom I'm assigning a decimal value.  I need to assign this value based on the combination of the lists that are above it in the hierarchy.  Each element of a particular list is an Enum value, so one combination could be Trees, Buildings, BuildingNumber.  And another Trees, Buildings, BuildingPrice.  What would be the best way of assigning values to these combinations?

The values I'm assigning *from* are coming from just an arbitrary class.  I will then need to do some calculations to some of those values to assign the new values in a particular combination.

```
public class Hierarchy1
{
    public List<Hierarchy2> NextList;
    public Hierarchy1Enum EnumValue;
}

public class Hierarchy2
{
    public List<Hierarchy3> NextList;
    public Hierarchy2Enum EnumValue;
}

public class Hierarchy3
{
    public decimal Value;
    public Hierarchy3Enum EnumValue;
}
```

Something like that.  The Enums each have 5-10 values so there's quite a few combinations.

Hierarchy1 will have a list of Hierarchy2's.  If there are 10 values in the Hierarchy2Enum, there will be 10 elements in that List (so essentially 1 element per enum).

Comment: Can you show some example code? I don't get your structure

Comment: Your structure will be better explained in code, not in english...

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you're looking for, but based on your code, it seems like you're trying to implement a non-binary tree structure. This link (http://bit.ly/62Vx9I) explains what a tree data structure is, and this link (http://bit.ly/10YfuV) explains how to implement a templated, non-binary tree in c#.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<Hierarchy1>();

    foreach (Hierarchy1Enum enum1 in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Hierarchy1Enum)))
    {
        var item1 = new Hierarchy1();

        list.Add(item1);

        item1.EnumValue = enum1;
        item1.NextList = new List<Hierarchy2>();

        foreach (Hierarchy2Enum enum2 in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Hierarchy2Enum)))
        {
            var item2 = new Hierarchy2();

            item1.NextList.Add(item2);

            item2.EnumValue = enum2;
            item2.NextList = new List<Hierarchy3>();

            foreach (Hierarchy3Enum enum3 in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Hierarchy3Enum)))
            {
                var item3 = new Hierarchy3();

                item2.NextList.Add(item3);

                item3.EnumValue = enum3;

                item3.Value = GetValue(enum1, enum2, enum3);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static decimal GetValue(Hierarchy1Enum enum1, Hierarchy2Enum enum2, Hierarchy3Enum enum3)
{
    return // Calculate your value from enum1, enum2 and enum3
}
```

Comment: Yes.  I've got that far.  But now what about GetValue? I have the combination of the 3 enums but don't know where to go from there. edit: my point is, I know the combination, but I can't create 1000 if/else statements for each combination.

Comment: You said that you get the values from an arbitrary class. Could you post the source of that class?

Comment: It's just a class with some double variables.  I'd be using these variables for some calculations based on the combination above.

Comment: Well it could be something like: if Hierarchy3Enum is a certain value, divide ArbitraryClass.DoubleValue by 20.  But which DoubleValue to use would be determined by the value of Hierarchy2Enum.

Comment: I don't think we can help you with that because this is business logic that is specific to your application. You have all the input you need (the three enum values) and you would decide how to calculate the result based on these values.

Comment: I guess maybe I didn't word my question very well.  I've since fixed the problem by using 3 switch statements.  One switch for each enum, and one case per enum member.  That covers each combination. I get the value based on one enum, then alter it based on the next two.